# Variable type change

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent, addeventlistener

How do I change this:

```
 canvas2.mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
```

To this functionality :

```
canvas2.addEventListener('mousedown', **then the functions here**);
```

I have tried these but they don't work:

```
 canvas2.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){handleMouseMove(e);}); 
 canvas2.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e)handleMouseMove(e));
 canvas2.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e),handleMouseMove(e));
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? For instance, why are you doing this? That original code looks like jQuery code to set up the handler, are you trying to migrate away?

Comment: I am trying to create a drawing function the code i have in all hand coded javascript, however this is jquery and i need to change the thing i have into an event listener so that i can remove the event listener later

Answer (score 1):

If the "from" you've shown works (or worked when you were using jQuery), `canvas2` is or was a jQuery object (most likely). The rough equivalent is your first line, but on the DOM element inside it:

```
canvas2[0].addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
```

or indeed, simply:

```
canvas2[0].addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseMove);
```

Naturally, if you're trying to migrate code away from jQuery, you'll probably end up changing `canvas2` to something else, perhaps a straight DOM object. If so, drop the `[0]` from the above when you do that. But as the first line of the things you've tried would have worked if that were *already* done, hopefully the above helps.

---

Side note: You changed from `handleMouseDown` to `handleMouseMove` in your examples. I've faithfully done that above, but do be sure you're using `mousedown` with `handleMouseDown` and `mousemove` with `handleMouseMove`...

Comment: unfortunatly this bit of code when replaced with the original did not work and yes the original was $('canvas') i changed it so that the code looked more like the thing i was trying to get to, to try and make it work

Comment: If the original was `$('canvas')`, then you may want `document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]` or `document.querySelector('canvas')` (which returns the first match).